# What methods are there currently that allow you to call a Go function in C?

Tags: c, compilation, go, cgo

I've seen lots of different ways this can be done, none of them seem ideal in terms of having to use lots of wrappers and callbacks. Is there a simple way of doing this?

For example, we have this:

```
//foo.go

package foo

import "C"

//export SayFive
func SayFive() int {
    return 5
}
```

This has been stripped down to the minimum now, and all I want to be able to do at this point is call that `SayFive` function in C.

However, not at the top of this file. It's very simple and useful to be able to do that, but I'm looking for a way like this:

```
//foo.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = SayFive();
}
```

I've seen in examples that are like the above, that `#include "_cgo_export.h"` which makes total sense, but when I've done that and tried to compile it, it fails.

Could anyone explain the whole process involved that would allow us to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call C from Go and Go from C, but **only** within the framework of a Go program.

So your example of a C program with a `main()` won't work, because that would be calling Go from within the framework of a C program.

In other words, Go can't make objects you can link statically or dynamically with C programs.

So you'll have to turn what you want to do on its head and make the Go program the master, and call the C program parts from it. That means the program with the `main()` function must be a Go program.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I was to run `go tool cgo foo.go` it will generate a bunch of C source files and headers (by default) in `_obj`. If there no way to use these in such a way that the master program could be written in C? That would involve using `#include "_cgo_export.h"`.

Comment: Very hard - Go and C memory management is very different and it needs Go to be in charge.  There is the matter of how you get the Go runtime in there too. I don't think this has ever been a goal of the Go developers so it wouldn't be easy!

Comment: I think the only way this could be done then is with gccgo, but I wanted to try without using that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do that?

Comment: @HarryLawrence Calling Go code from a C program is not supported yet. Support *may* come but is quite difficult to get right, mainly because of Go's complex threading model and its garbage collection.

Comment: @OneOfOne to be honest right now it's nothing essential or important, I'm just experimenting with it and was just wondering if it was possible. So far I have been able to do it, but only with gccgo.